# How to center a form using material-ui only?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to learn Material-UI and tried creating a "form" looking at their documentation (I had some difficulties understanding the pacing of the documentation and don't know if I've actually used the intended tags for creating a form :P). Regardless, I want to center my "form", and after fiddling about with the codes from Material-UI documentation and my knowledge about css, I managed to center the "form", horizontally only however and can't seem to get it centered vertically. I don't yet know how to use my own css code along with the functionalities provided in material-ui and in-fact want this to be purely material-ui since i feel like using css with Material-UI will make everything more complicated when I start developing large scale applications using a mix of both material-ui and css for styling. Is there any way to center a form using pure material-ui code only?

Here's my code for the component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Button, TextField, FormControl, Container, Paper, Box, Grid} from '@material-ui/core'

class Login extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center" justify="center">
                <Paper>
                    <form>
                        <Box> 
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined" label="Username"/>
                        </Box>
                        <Box>
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined" label="Password"/>
                        </Box>
                        <Box>
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Login</Button>
                            <a href="Register.js">Register</a>
                        </Box>
                    </form>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>   
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

Comment: You will have to specify a height for the container.

Answer (score 1):

You should get rid of the thought that you should not customize components using custom css, because that's what most react UI frameworks/libs implement the override function for.

And since MUI uses flexbox, it's a matter of seconds to center your content inside your container!

```css
/* LoginComponent.css */

/* Since Material UI uses the modern flexbox implementation, we can use justify-content and align-items */
.centerMyForm {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
// LoginComponent.js
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {Button, TextField, FormControl, Container, Paper, Box, Grid} from '@material-ui/core'

import './LoginComponent.css' // We import your custom css.

class Login extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <Grid container direction="row" alignItems="center" justify="center">
                <Paper>
                    <form className="centerMyForm"> {/* We add your custom class name here to center the form */}
                        <Box> 
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined" label="Username"/>
                        </Box>
                        <Box>
                            <TextField id="outlined-basic" variant="outlined" label="Password"/>
                        </Box>
                        <Box>
                            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">Login</Button>
                            <a href="Register.js">Register</a>
                        </Box>
                    </form>
                </Paper>
            </Grid>   
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

Further reading:

- Align items: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items
- Flexbox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox